# clear all series from a chart, then replot

Tags: vb.net, charts

Simple problem - I'm trying to plot a couple of series on a chart, then change the selection, delete the old series and plot a new series. The code below works the first time though, but gives an error `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` on subsequent execution which I don't understand. A Google search didn't help. There has to be a simple bullet proof method? Thanks for any help.

```
For Each Series In chrtPAYOFF.Series
    chrtPAYOFF.Series.Clear()
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
YourChart.Series(0).Points.Clear()
YourChart.Series(1).Points.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

A single line of code `chrtPAYOFF.Series.Clear()` clears **all** series and allows new ones to be plotted. I thought it was more complex and each series needed to be deleted.